# How to reach next div from input inside another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The code below, input doesn't change display property for the div with the class "divToFindWithClass". Where's the problem?

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="radio-inline radio-primary">
            <input value="1" type="radio" name="xxxx" class="required styled" onclick="$(this).closest('div').next('.divToFindWithClass').css('display','block');">
            Yes
        </label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 divToFindWithClass" style="display: none">
        <label>Label</label>
        <br />
        <input name="file" type="file" class="styled">
</div>
```

Comment: place your jquery code here..

Comment: You can see it from input's onclick event definition.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle showing the problem? Seems to work... http://jsbin.com/newimuqi/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    <input value="1" type="radio" name="xxxx" class="required styled" onclick="$(this).parents('div').next('.divToFindWithClass').css('display','block');">
```

Answer (score 0):

did this using jquery...

did some modification to the class name, pls go through

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".requiredstyled").click(function (event) {
           $(this).closest('div').next('.divToFindWithClass').css('display','block');
            });
             });

        </script>


<div class="col-sm-4">
        <label class="radio-inline radio-primary">
            <input value="1" type="radio" name="xxxx" class="requiredstyled" />
             Yes
        </label>
</div>
<div class="divToFindWithClass" style="display: none">
        <label>Label</label>
        <br />
        <input name="file" type="file" class="styled" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use following way => Separation of JavaScript/jQuery from HTML ,

```
<label class="radio-inline radio-primary">
    <input value="1" type="radio" name="xxxx" class="required styled" id="inputRadio" >
    Yes
</label>

<script>
$("#inputRadio").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('div').next('.divToFindWithClass').css('display','block');
});
</script>
```